# Thunderbird missing Password

Tags: server, password, thunderbird

Im using Ubuntu 17.04 with Thunderbird 52.4.0 (64-Bit). It all worked good until some days ago. I wrked with Thunderbird all fine. On the same day I restarted the computer and Thunderbird, but it could no longer connect to the server, neither smtp or pop3. When I try to call the mails from the server it tries to, tells it is connected to the server but after a while it stops trying without error message. When I try to send a mail, I get the following message: "Senden der Nachricht fehlgeschlagen.
Fehler beim Senden der Nachricht: Passwort für smtp.livenet.ch ist nicht verfügbar. Die Nachricht wurde nicht gesendet." (Sorry for the German, it means: Error by sending: Password for smpt.... not available)
But it does not ask for the password.
The window with the stored passwords is empty.
I tried to reinstall Thunderbird without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Thunderbird refused to remember the passwords (it did ask for the passwords everytime though, so maybe my solution doesn't work for you. But it can't hurt to check the following:

Go to your installed add-ons and check if the KDE-Wallet add-on is installed. If so, disable this add-on and restart firefox.

I also disabled KDE-Wallet on my system since I have no use for it.

This solved it in my case.